# Apache camel onException adding error details to the original message

Tags: java, apache-camel, mq

I have added this exception handling to the camel route.

```
 .onException(BeanCreationException.class, ValidationException.class)
     .handled(true)
     .process(new OnExceptionProcessor())
     .to("errorQueue0").id("errorQueue")
     .end()
```

```
public class OnExceptionProcessor implements Processor {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        Exception cause = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Exception.class);
        exchange.getIn().setHeader("FailedBecause", cause.getMessage());
    }
}
```

When I read this message back from the error queue, I cannot find this header.
any idea on how to add error details along with the original message to the error queue

Comment: Maybe wrap it in an object in the body?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a **context problem** because you are **in a processor that is called by the error handler**.

As an alternative, you could **return the String value to set** in the header **from your processor method**. By the way, this also **improves the testability** of your Processor.

Then you can **use this return value to set the header in the error handler route** directly.

```
.setHeader("FailedBecause", method(new OnExceptionProcessor()))
```